# Include Sphinx-generated documentation in master file

Tags: include, sphinx

I'm currently working on a project (for university) that will be documented with LaTeX. About one third of the documentation will be about a python module that I've written.

I'm looking for a clean way to include the documentation generated by Sphinx into my main document. I think it would be possible to fiddle with the generated doc (remove preamble, move required `\usepackage`-commands in my main file, shift all headings down one level, etc.) and then include it, but I really hope that there is a better way.

I don't think that using Sphinx for the whole document would be a good idea since I'm not that confident in using it for more than code documentation.

Any hints are really appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  You can use `rst2latex.py` to convert rst documentation into latex. It is sometimes a little rough but mostly OK.

Comment: Thanks for the `rst2latex`-hint, but does this cover the documentation pulled from the python code? E.g. auto-generated method signatures.

Comment: I've never done this, so I'm not sure...my impression though is that sphinx can be configured to do precisely this...I'm pretty sure that this is what [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) does to produce its manuals. Sorry that I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 4):

It took me some time to figure this out, but as I just wanted to do the exact same thing, here you go 9 months later:

1. Copy `sphinx.sty`  to your main projects folder
2. Add the following packages to your main file preamble:

   ```
   \usepackage{standalone}
   \usepackage{sphinx}
   ```
3. Include your sphinx documentation like this:

   ```
   \part*{Appendix}
   \phantomsection
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}
   \appendix
   \def\maketitle{}
   \def\tableofcontents{}
   \input{../project_name/doc/_build/latex/project_name}
   ```

This adds a nice, unnumbered part to the TOC and gives all the documentation sections letters as section numbering. It works for me with a completely untouched sphinx LaTeX output.

Comment: Why copy `tabulary.sty`?

Comment: Hmm, it is supplied with the sphinx output and required by ``sphinx.sty``, so I figured that might be a good idea.

But you could probably load it from CTAN just as well, I'll edit that out.

Comment: Please note that this will fail with more recent Sphinx versions: there are more `sphinx*.sty` files in latex build repertory that you need to copy over if you want the latex code to be inserted into some other non-Sphinx generated document.